# Converts RGB values into Hex values without using toString(16)

Tags: javascript

I need my function to convert RGB decimal values into Hexadecimal values without using toString(16). This is what I have. Why isn't it working? Is it because I have more than one switch statement so it completes the iteration without completing the second one?

```
function rgb(r, g, b){
 let result = '';
 // Convert into array for iteration
 let arr = [r,g,b];
 // Iterate through each color
 for(let i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
  if (arr[i] > 255) result += 'FF';
  if (arr[i] < 0) result += '00';

 // Convert first iteration into hex format
  switch (Math.floor(arr[i]/16)) {
   case 10: result += 'A';break;
   case 11: result += 'B';break;
   case 12: result += 'C';break;
   case 13: result += 'D';break;
   case 14: result += 'E';break;
   case 15: result += 'F';break;
   default: result += (Math.floor(arr[i]/16) + '');
  }

 // Convert second iteration into hex format
  switch (((arr[i]/16)-16)*16) {
   case 10: result += 'A';break;
   case 11: result += 'B';break;
   case 12: result += 'C';break;
   case 13: result += 'D';break;
   case 14: result += 'E';break;
   case 15: result += 'F';break;
   default: result += ((((arr[i]/16)-16)*16) + '');
  }
 }
return result;
}

// function should return the following results.
rgb(255, 255, 255) // returns FFFFFF
rgb(255, 255, 300) // returns FFFFFF
rgb(0,0,0) // returns 000000
rgb(148, 0, 211) // returns 9400D3
```

Answer (score 0):

A problem is that, when turning a number (eg, 255) into two characters, calculating the second character by using

```
((arr[i]/16)-16)*16
```

is not the right calculation. You want a range of 0 to 15 - taking out the multiples of 16 until you're left with 0 to 15. Just use `% 16`.

Another problem is that you're `switch`ing even if past the range of 0 to 255 - break instead so that the rest of the loop body does not execute in such cases.

```js
function rgb(r, g, b){
 let result = '';
 // Convert into array for iteration
 let arr = [r,g,b];
 // Iterate through each color
 for(let i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
  if (arr[i] > 255) {
    result += 'FF';
    break;
  }
  if (arr[i] < 0) {
    result += '00';
    break;
  }
 // Convert first iteration into hex format
  switch (Math.floor(arr[i]/16)) {
   case 10: result += 'A';break;
   case 11: result += 'B';break;
   case 12: result += 'C';break;
   case 13: result += 'D';break;
   case 14: result += 'E';break;
   case 15: result += 'F';break;
   default: result += (Math.floor(arr[i]/16) + '');
  }
 // Convert second iteration into hex format
  switch (arr[i] % 16) {
   case 10: result += 'A';break;
   case 11: result += 'B';break;
   case 12: result += 'C';break;
   case 13: result += 'D';break;
   case 14: result += 'E';break;
   case 15: result += 'F';break;
   default: result += arr[i] % 16;
  }
 }
return result;
}

console.log(rgb(255, 255, 255)) // returns FFFFFF
console.log(rgb(255, 255, 300)) // returns FFFFFF
console.log(rgb(0,0,0)) // returns 000000
console.log(rgb(148, 0, 211)) // returns 9400D3
```